# List<dynamic>().Add problem C#

Tags: c#

When I loop into the List, I always see the same value for all the items in the list.

Where am I going wrong?

here is what i did.

```
var DyObjectsList = new List<dynamic>; 
dynamic DyObj = new ExpandoObject(); 
if (condition1)
 { DyObj.Required = true;
   DyObj.Message = "Message 1"; 
   DyObjectsList.Add(DyObj); } 
if (condition2)
 { DyObj.Required = false;
   DyObj.Message = "Message 2"; 
   DyObjectsList.Add(DyObj); 
 }
```

......

interestingly all the items in DyObjectsList are replaced with the values of the last assigned object.

Comment: Your adding multiple references to the same object.

Comment: ... and you're assigning properties of the same object, where it seems you might expect there to be different instances.

Comment: We cannot help you only with the piece of code available here. Considering only this code only one object's reference is being added to the List. Please tell us the context of this code. Is it in a loop? Is it part of a function?

Comment: Perhaps you should replace "if (condition2)" with "else" because your code seems to imply that condition1 and condition2 shouldn't both be true.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to instantiate a new instance inside the body of the `if` statements (otherwise you are repeatedly modifying/adding a reference to the same instance):

```
if (condition1) { 
    dynamic DyObj = new ExpandoObject(); 
    DyObj.Required = true;
    DyObj.Message = "Message 1"; 
    DyObjectsList.Add(DyObj); } 
if (condition2) {
    dynamic DyObj = new ExpandoObject(); 
    DyObj.Required = false;
    DyObj.Message = "Message 2"; 
    DyObjectsList.Add(DyObj); 
}
```

Of course, even better is:

```
if(condition1) {
    dynamic obj = GetNewDynamicObject(false, "Message 1");
    DyObjectsList.Add(obj);
}
if(condition2) {
    dynamic obj = GetNewDynamicObject(true, "Message 2");
    DyObjectsList.Add(obj);
}
```

where the definition of `GetNewDynamicObject` is obvious.

Comment: It's been awhile since I've played with dynamics, shouldn't it be `dynamic obj = GetNewDynamicObject(false, "Message 1");` though?

Answer (score 4):

You're adding the same object twice, and changing its properties in the middle.

You need to add a `new ExpandoObject()` every time.

Answer (score 0):

When both conditions are true, then the variables will be set as in the last if block. You should probably use else if instead of second if block.